# On restart, start with "monitor all" enabled

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, monit

I have `monit` enabled and monitoring one of my applications, where
if the application restarts more than 4 times in 10 cycles, I stop
it, and run a script (which, among other action, also does `unmonitor all`,
and stops `monit`)

Now, if I manually start my application and `monit` again, `monit` starts
out with monitoring disabled on all the applications. Is it possible to 
say somewhere in the `monitrc` or other configs to `monitor all` on start?

I could have issued the command `monit monitor all` from my scripts, but
there is a `startup delay` configured for `monit`, and I will have to 
wait until the `HTTP` connection is up, to issue the command. Instead
it will be good to have `monit` start with monitoring enabled for `all`.

I am on the latest `5.17`, built from source on Ubuntu trusty.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to specify `monitor all` within a configuration file, rather than issuing a `unmonitor all` why not just stop `monit`?

Comment: No, there is no such config called `monitor all` that can be added in the `monit` config file. The reason I need to unmonitor is because of the counters - if I dont do this, the restart counters are not reset

Comment: Maybe you could try to delete the monit state file in order to reset the counter. Default monitoring mode is on, so deleting the file would remove all your unmonitor flags and counter values). Doc says : `-s statefile Write state information to this file. Or use "set statefile" in monitrc.`